# Combining multiple regex expressions

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have to perform multiple operations on few string to sanitize them. I have been able to do so but in multiple operations in **`bash`** as,

```
#   Getting the Content between START and END
    var1=$(sed '/START/,/END/!d;//d' <<< "$content")

#   Getting the 4th Line
    var2=$(sed '4q;d' <<< "$content")

#   Stripping all the new lines
    var1=${var1//$'\n'/}
    var2=${var2//$'\n'/}

#   Escaping the double quotes i.e. A"B => A\"B
    var1=$(sed "s/\"/\\\\\"/g" <<< "$var1")
    var2=$(sed "s/\"/\\\\\"/g" <<< "$var2")

#   Removing the contents wrapped in brackets i.e. A[...]B => AB
    var1=$(sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' <<< "$var1")
    var2=$(sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' <<< "$var2")
```

No doubt it's extremely bad to read the same thing over and over again when the same can be done in single operation. 
Any suggestions?

Working Example:

**`SAMPLE INPUT`**

```
   [1][INTRO]
   [2][NAV]

   ABAQUESNE, Masséot

... 

START

   French ceramist, who was the first grand-master of the glazed pottery
   at Sotteville-ls-Rouen (20 years before [8]Bernard Palissy). He took
   part in the development of the ceramic factory of Rouen. He was the
   author - among others - of the ceramic triptych representing the Flood
   (1550, couen, Muse de la Renaissance).

END
```

**`DESIRED OUTPUT`**

```
ABAQUESNE, Masséot
French ceramist, who was the first grand-master of the glazed pottery at Sotteville-ls-Rouen (20 years before Bernard Palissy). He took part in the development of the ceramic factory of Rouen. He was the author - among others - of the ceramic triptych representing the Flood (1550, couen, Muse de la Renaissance).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk for this:

```
awk 'NR==4{sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/, ""); print}' file
```

```
ABAQUESNE, Masséot
```

and 2nd awk:

```
awk '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/, "")}
/^START/{p=1; next}
/^END/{sub(/\[[^]]*\]/, "", s); gsub(/"/, "\\\\&", s); print s; p=0; next}
p{s = s $0}' file
```

```
French ceramist, who was the first grand-master of the glazed potteryat Sotteville-ls-Rouen (20 years before Bernard Palissy). He tookpart in the development of the ceramic factory of Rouen. He was theauthor - among others - of the ceramic triptych representing the Flood(1550, couen, Muse de la Renaissance).
```

Comment: Thanks, but i was looking to store outputs in 2 different variables, although i can stream output of this in another sed to do so but if it's possible from here? Also, i want to escape `"` too, forgot to add that in example.